# How do i get all child records in mvc5 using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database structure

```
users
 --username
 --ProfileId
 --passwordhash

Profile
 --Id
 --name

Drives
 --id
 -- name

userDrives
 --Id
 --ProfileId
 --DriveId
```

I am looking to get all the drives of the current logged in user. I normally would have written a stored procedure to get the desired results. But i am trying to use linq for the first time(learning) and getting back into asp.net programming after years of working on other technologies.

Please bear with if the question is very newbieish

Comment: Database access doesn't have anything to do with what type of web project you are working on, or even whether it's a web project at all.  When you say linq, are you referring to linq to SQL?  It has pretty much been deprecated in favor of Entity Framework.

Comment: Sorry, i havent been clear enough in my question. I am using entity framework 6. I am just trying to use join table to get all the drive records for the current user. I dont want to go the normal stored procedure route, as i am told its better querying from C#. Correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

**How to get all drives for the current user?**

When using Entity Framework you can add navigation properties to your entities. Navigation properties represent relationships between entities. Here you have a one-to-many relationship between Drive and Profile, you can add navigation properties to your entities like this:

- add `ICollection<Drive>` property to `Profile` entity.
- add `Profile` property to `Drive` entity.
- add `User` property to `Profile` entity.
- add `Profile` property to `User` entity.

When you have an instance of an user, you can use `user.Profile.Drives` to retrieve it's drives (here Drives is `ICollection<Drive>`). You can also use it to add new drives to that user, don't forget to call `SaveChanges` at the end. When using navigation properties you should take care that EF is able to create proxies for you entities, otherwise they will be null since EF cannot do lazy loading on your instances. If you want more information about this subject you should look for [Entity Framework Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx).

Comment: Thanks agarwaen.. I figured that out.. How do i write the query. In my case i have the user entity which is linked to profile entity and profile is linked to userDrive and which in turn is linked to drive

Comment: @Prady sorry, I didn't realize that user and profile are distinct entities. Take a look at the updated answer, is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to:

var result=(from u in user Join ud in userdrives On u.ProfileId equals ud.ProfileId Join d in drives On ud.DriveId equals d.id Where u.username == loggedinUsername Select d).ToList ();